# Use predefined Office documents in Web Add-in

Tags: ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I have a requirement to create Web Add-in for Power Point that will change both document content and meta data. Let's call these changes templates.

The Add-in task pane will contain a drop down list for all possible templates. 
When the user choose one of them and click apply button, selected template will be applied.

Each template has to add a header, a footer and custom properties to the document.

As Office.js API is not supporting custom properties manipulation, I'm thinking about defining all templates, as PPT documents with proper headers, footers and custom properties, manually. When a user decides to apply a specific template, I will copy the content of the current PPT document to selected template (existing PPT document) and continue working on the template behind the scenes.

Giving this scenario, is it possible to:

1. Have some predefined PPT documents as templates in an Office Web Add-in
2. Copy the content of PPT document to a another one and continue working on the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good question.. here is some guidance for you:

1. Unfortunately, this is not possible to implement as a Web Add-In in PPT today.
2. The PPT JS API is still not as rich as in Word or Excel.
3. I recommend you to create a VSTO Add-In for this scenario.
4. Please add this request to our [user voice channel](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Thanks!